# How to format strings into a lined-up format in C?

Tags: c, string, formatting

How can I format string to ensure that it is shown as:

```
ID:12            SIZE:235235235235
ID:1455          SIZE:335235
```

Instead of:

```
ID:12         SIZE:235235235235
ID:1455         SIZE:335235
```

Tabs do NOT work in all cases, they only help with this if the length variance is +/- 4-5 characters.

Is there something equivalent to Padding(VB) in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print something with `printf`, you can specify a field width; the value is justified in the field. For example:

```
printf("ID: %5d SIZE: %10d", id, size);
```

will right-justify the id in a 5-character field, and the size in a 10-character field.

Comment: Is it possible to left-justify?

Comment: Add a negative sign in front of the 5 or 10 to left-justify. You might want to look at http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf.